# CSS3 transitioning/transforming

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I am trying to animate certain elements using only css, as you can see in the code below, everything is working fine as far as animation goes, the problem is in the space created by the elements which being animated. Ideally there should be no white space when the elements are out of view. In my try below `if ( x === true )` works fine the extra space is created for the element and then the element moves in the new space created, but when the second part of the if statement `else` is executed the process reverses, the space for the element goes away and then the element is animated out of the view while overlapping the elements below it.

I hope I haven't messed up too much above... :(

in short :

1.`<div class="animateX_def">` should not take any space on the page

2.`<a id="animateMe">` is clicked, space is created for `<div class="animateX_def">`

3.`<div class="animateX_def">` animates itself into the new space created for it.

4. When `<a id="animateMe">` is clicked again, the `<div class="animateX_def">`animates itself out of the view.
5. The space which `<div class="animateX_def">` was taking goes away.

How do I do that ? What's wrong with my code ?

HTML

```
<a id="animateMe" href="#">Click me</a>

<div class="animateX_def" style="position: absolute;">

    <div class="child_element">
        ---
    </div>
    ---
    ---

</div>
```

CSS

```
.animateX_def {
    transition:All 600ms ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition:All 600ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:All 600ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:All 600ms ease-in-out;

    transform: scale(0) translate(-999px);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0) translate(-999px);
    -moz-transform: scale(0) translate(-999px);
    -o-transform: scale(0) translate(-999px);
    -ms-transform: scale(0) translate(-999px);
}

.animateX {
    transform: scale(1) translate(0px);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1) translate(0px);
    -moz-transform: scale(1) translate(0px);
    -o-transform: scale(1) translate(0px);
    -ms-transform: scale(1) translate(0px);
}
```

Javascript

```
var x = true;

$ ( '#animateMe' ).click ( function ( event ) { 

        if ( x === true )
        {
                $ ( '.animateX_def' ).css ( 'position', 'static' );
                $ ( '.animateX_def' ).toggleClass ( 'animateX' );
                x = false;
        }
        else
        {

                $ ( '.animateX_def' ).toggleClass ( 'animateX' );
                $ ( '.animateX_def' ).css ( 'position', 'absolute' );
                x = true;
        }

        event.preventDefault (  );
        event.stopPropagation (  );

} );
```

Comment: I've updated the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/exodha1a/ this has a yellow background on the element to show the animation. But once the animation is complete the div is not occupying any space, so I think your code is right?

Comment: @lharby see what happens when you put another div : https://jsfiddle.net/exodha1a/1/

Comment: OK but you don't want a block of white below the click button where the animated div comes in do you? I mean currently the behaviour is correct.

Comment: @lharby what's actually happening is that, the css property "position" changes even before the animation is started which creates a messy look, the animated element now overlaps other elements which are below it.

Comment: It's possible to pass in a callback function as part of the toggleClass function, like this: `animateX.toggleClass ( 'animateX', function(){
                 animateX.css ( 'position', 'static' );
                });` but I am still not seeing good results in the fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `max-height`. It's not ideal solution because required static value for "open" state.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/daaym4ck/ And for **only css** solution I added `input[type="checkbox"]` for open/close state control.

**UPDATE:** Ok, `height` work to, but only with fixed values, `max-height` a little bit flexible for unknown or variable height. Just set it on possible maximum. But keep in mind, if you have real element `height: 20px`, and specified in styles `max-height: 200px` and `transition-duration: 1000ms`, your element reach their height in 100 ms (20px/200px * 1000ms).

Comment: Is there a way to achieve it with height: auto ?

Comment: No. You can't apply transition to dynamic height.

Comment: I updated my answer for explanation of height and max-height usage.